# Reading Row Data from a spreadsheet

Tags: c#, .net, xlsx, spreadsheetlight

Using the [tools SpreadSheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/) I cant find how to read the rows of a spreadsheet file. Specificly Sheet 1.

Two problems Im having is

1. There is no way that I can see to get the Rows
2. There is no way that I can see to get the Column Index
   Here is my code

   ```
   public void ParseExcelFile(FileInfo file) 
   {
       using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
       {
           FileStream fs = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open);

           MemoryStream msFirstPass = new MemoryStream();
           SLDocument sheet1 = new SLDocument(fs, "Sheet1");


           // There is no way that I can see to get the Rows
           foreach(var row in sheet1.Rows)
           {
               foreach(SLCell c in row)
               {
                   // There is no way that I can see to get the Column Index
                   switch(c.Column )
                   {
                       case 1:
                           //Handle data if cell is Column 1
                           break;
                       case 2:
                           //Handle data if cell is Column 2
                           break;
                       case 3:
                           //Handle data if cell is Column 3
                           break;
                   }
               }
           }



       }

   }//func
   ```

Comment: Same problem. Could you please provide some info here as you have already accepted the answer?

Comment: @Sandy See my suggested solution below with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its going to be hard for people to answer this as SpreadSheetLight doesn't appear to have publicly available code documentation. I have two suggestions based on a couple of assumptions:

1. Does the SLDocument.Row.SLCell class have any index property? If so you could get your required information from there.
2. You could replace your foreach's with for's to track the row and column.

Comment: Actually, there's quite a bit of info here: http://spreadsheetlight.com/sample-code/

Comment: ... api [help file in chm format](http://spreadsheetlight.com/downloads/SpreadsheetLight.chm) also available

Answer (score 4):

The code below would read each row (assuming file is the file path to the Excel file):

```
using (SLDocument sl = new SLDocument())
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
    SLDocument sheet = new SLDocument(fs, "Table 1");

    SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sheet.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    for (int j = 1; j < stats.EndRowIndex; j++)
    {
        // Get the first column of the row (SLS is a 1-based index)
        var value = sheet.GetCellValueAsString(j, 1);
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = @"Test.xlsx";

using FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
using SLDocument sl = new SLDocument(fs);

var worksheetNames = sl.GetWorksheetNames();
foreach (var worksheetName in worksheetNames)
{
    sl.SelectWorksheet(worksheetName);
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sl.GetWorksheetStatistics();
    for (var i = 1; i <= stats.NumberOfRows; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 1; j <= stats.NumberOfColumns; j++)
        {
            var value = sl.GetCellValueAsString(i, j);
            Console.WriteLine(value);
        }
    }
}
```